# What is the best way to dispute review audits

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

**Is there a way to deal with audits that we disagree with other than to post about it in meta?**

I recently failed [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/4712561). The question asked how to get out of a `for` loop when they couldn't use `break`. The answer under review was simply

> You can assign test to i when you want to stop looping.

Which I interpret as the person saying use

```
i = test
```

to stop the loop. Normally this would be a reasonable way to exit a `for` loop. However for this question it doesn't work because of an asynchronous call. The answer was appropriately downvoted because it does not work. Then, according to the comment

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

it appears that it was deleted because people believed it should have been a comment, even though it really was an answer. Just one that didn't work.

I know that at least one other time that I've failed an audit, it was a similar situation. I looked at the answer, thought that it was a legitimate (though wrong) answer, and then selected "No Action Needed" because I thought downvotes and not deleting was the appropriate response.

Is there a way to deal with audits that we disagree with other than to post about it in meta? In particular, I feel like there is a class of reviews that are really just judgement calls. The answer being deleted or the question being closed is okay, but they're also not so bad that they need to be. I don't think it is helpful if review-audits use one of these - someone could disagree even after carefully reviewing. It would be nice to have some way to disallow those types of reviews from being chosen by the auditing system.

Also, what's the threshold for receiving a review ban? I've passed most audits I've been given and only failed infrequently, but I received a review ban of two days as a result of failing this time.

Comment: Just found [these guidelines for the low-quality review queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180029#180029). It says "Note that **wrong answers should not be deleted**".

Comment: When you were presented with the answer, did it have a score?  Were you able to see the comments below the answer?  An answer like that is very unlikely to impart any useful information, unless the question is specifically "how do I know when to stop looping?"  Even then, the answer would only be a partial one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yet, is it still an answer? If so, how come it should be deleted through VLQQ nevertheless?

Comment: @JanDvorak: If I understand your question, you're asking if "this answer is unsalvageable by editing" is actionable (i.e. subjects an answer to deletion)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey The score it showed me was zero, and it did not show me any of the comments. We can't up- or down-vote a question from the late-answer queue, otherwise I would have down-voted it.

Comment: Do you agree that the answer is low-quality?  Was the queue asking you if deletion was recommended?  Were you, in fact, in the Low-Quality queue?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, I agree it is low-quality, though I felt the answer would have been salvageable. In hindsight I realize that I should have tried to comment on it to prompt the answerer to add some more explanation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the consensus on meta is that wrong answers should not be deleted. Has that changed? Or is there a difference between "useless answers" and "useful answers if they were correct, but they are wrong"?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was in the late answers queue.

Comment: @JanDvorak: My concern is that this is not a "Not an Answer" queue.  I'm reviewing those articles right now.

Comment: @RobWatts: OK, so here's my take.  This is one of those audits that probably shouldn't be an audit.  It's most likely in the queue in part because it got 4 downvotes.  In my opinion, that's awfully severe, since in principle (even though it is low-quality), it does attempt to answer the question.  In the future, if there's an inkling of doubt on these, *go to the actual post and review it in its entirety.*  You'll be able to see all of the votes and comments, as well as the question.  This is especially true of reviews with a score of 0 and no comments (can often be indicative of an audit).

Comment: @JanDvorak: For Very Low Quality, I'm inclined to follow [this advice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197568/102937).  Note that, to follow it, you actually *do* have to look at the question.  The guidance on not deleting answers that are wrong is mostly applicable to Not an Answer (since wrong answers clearly are answers).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I like step #2. Let's see how much better it aligns with my intuition about what should be deleted. So far my guess is that it will align perfectly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Good point about going to the actual post. Though, in the late-answers queue it seems pretty common for there to be no votes or comments yet.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Naturally, if an answer is really a new question, or an attempt to communicate with someone, or an edit to the OP, then you can treat it like you would usually treat an NAA.

Comment: @RobWatts: There's always "skip," if you're not sure.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The advice you linked to is pretty good. In particular, I like this point - "Folks whose worthless answers are deleted are free to come back and post new ones with clear, useful information if they care to."

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Actually, I think what happened here was the same as what went on in this case: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/226595/135615 . The answer had a couple of "not an answer" flags on it that moderators or reviewers probably would have declined, but when the poster deleted their own answer the system automatically marked those as helpful. This then caused the answer to be used as an audit case, which it really shouldn't be. I'm pretty sure it was the auto-approved flags and not the downvotes that caused it to be used as an audit.

Comment: @BradLarson: Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: @BradLarson this sounds like a case for a feature request / bug report. Is there one already?