# Is it relatively more difficult to get an answer to Ruby questions?

Tags: discussion

I used to do .NET development, and whenever I asked a question, I got a pretty good answer pretty quickly.

Lately, I stopped using .NET, and I am doing Ruby and Rails development. Most of the time, it is much more difficult to get an answer. And most of the answers I get are relatively low in quality.

I am guessing the community at SO, though open to any question from any programming language, skewed towards .NET developers, or maybe there are not as many Ruby developers on SO.

Is that the case, or is it just me?

Comment: ... but this does give you a good oppertunity to improve the questions and answers on Ruby and Rails. You already recognize low quality answers and with your solid background in .net you should be able to leave better answers in no time. And by doing that SO and those tags get more interesting and will attract more people including experienced users.

Comment: It's a bit like Ruby itself - you have to wait ten times as long to get answers to Ruby questions compared with questions on other languages.

Comment: That'll teach ya.

Comment: I just had the exact same thought.  Googling that thought brought me here.

Answer (score 1):

Every programming language has its own dedicated community, and some of them are larger than others.

> I am guessing the community at SO, though open to any question from any programming language, skewed towards .NET developers, or maybe there are not as many Ruby developers on SO.

You can confirm this by looking at the number of questions tagged [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) (*not even including language-specific tags*), compared to the number of questions in [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby).

> And most of the answers I get are relatively low in quality.

Again, this varies by the community.  While I don't hear many people complaining about the quality in [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby), at least [it's not as bad as](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283428/359284) [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell),

Comment: I've heard Php is worst... but I only heard about it. Might be a myth.

Comment: Plus .NET has Jon Skeet. That makes it better by default :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the tag info pages for [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/topusers) and [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers) (click on the tag and click "top users" near the top to get to that page for any tag), it looks like it's slightly easier to get an answer to a Ruby question. The "unanswered" figures on those pages tell you what percentage of questions don't get any answers that are either accepted or upvoted at least once. The numbers for Ruby are a little bit lower for the last 7 days, 30 days, and all time.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about the quality of the answers, and also the type of the questions that didn't get an answer. Interesting figures nevertheless.

Comment: @hattenn It's not a perfect measuring system, but upvotes do say something about the quality of the answers.

Comment: Maybe a lot of ruby questions don't get upvotes because there's not much of a ruby community on SO though...

Comment: @levininja There are 48.7k followers of the Ruby tag. Far less than the 226k followers of the C# tag, but it's still a pretty large community.