# How to remove a question from an audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I recently stumbled upon an audit question that might qualify for being too broad, IMO. I tapped "Close", but fortunately the randomly selected "close" reason indicated me that it could be an audit, and indeed it was.

Now the question is, how can I prevent this question from being used as an audit? The question has upvotes, and is not bad, but other people might be thrown away by the style the question was asked.

Casting a close vote AFAIK will have this effect, however I don't want to use my close votes in a manner like this, even if I retract the vote later. Editing is also an option, however considering that English is not my first language, I usually refrain from editing questions that have good english.

Note that I have nothing against the question. I'm asking on a more general topic on how can we instruct the system to mark good questions as not viable for audit.

Comment: IIRC casting a close vote and then immediately retracting it should be enough. I will post a link discussing that if I can find one.

Comment: @duplode yes, I was aware of this workaround, however that seems a little unfair for the question. Do you know if casting a close vote (even if quickly retracting it) has any other effects on the question?

Comment: I think it is reasonable to suppose there aren't any other negative effects, though I don't have hard evidence of that. (Also, for the sake of completeness, I first found out about the workaround through [this comment by gnat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283428/remove-haskell-questions-from-review-audits#comment143182_283485).)

Comment: (Oops... only now I noticed that the "...even if I retract the vote later" remark in your question was there from the start. Sorry!)